# ngResource elimina la / final

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, restful

Estoy aprendiendo [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) y tengo problemas al usar [ngresource](/questions/tagged/ngresource) para consultar mi API.

Para empezar, estoy creando una *factoría* para configurar todo esto.

#### Archivo `home.factory.js`

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  policyFactory.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function policyFactory($resource){
    var token = '1001be33f57d902067f9def4fdd55f8bcc1768fd';
    return $resource('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/:policyID/', {policyID:'@id'}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + token},
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/'
      }
    });
  }

  angular.module('cmi')
    .factory('policyFactory', policyFactory);
})();
```

Esta *factoría* la uso en un controlador (que tengo en otro archivo):

#### Archivo `home.controller.js`

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  // PolicyHomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'policyHomeService'];
  PolicyHistoryController.$inject = ['$scope', 'policyFactory'];


  function PolicyHistoryController($scope, policyFactory){
    var self = this;
    self.policyData = {};

    policyFactory.query(function(data){
      self.policyData = data;
    });
  }

  angular.module('cmi')
    // .controller('PolicyHomeController', PolicyHomeController)
    .controller('PolicyHistoryController', PolicyHistoryController);
})();
```

> **Nota**
>   Aunque es muy probable que mi controlador `PolicyHistoryController` tenga algún error, el problema en este momento es, *en mi humilde opinión*, otro.

Como pueden observar, llamo a mi *recurso* (como sinónimo de *resource*) con la URL `'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/'`, especificada en la configuración de la factoría, y específico el método con el que hago la consulta (o *query*): `method: 'GET'`.

## Problema

Sin embargo, cuando la página se actualiza se hace una solicitud al servidor y se elimina la diagonal final y se convierte de

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/
```

en

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies
```

Sin esa diagonal final, el servidor me devuelve una respuesta 404 y provoca un error:

```
# El servidor
WARNING "GET /api/v1/policies HTTP/1.1" 404 16663
```

La respuesta esperada es algo como esto:

```
(cmi) [toledano ~/proyectos/cmi/client (master *)]$ http GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/ 'Authorization: Token 1001be33f57d902067f9def4fdd55f8bcc1768fd'
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 21 Aug 2016 00:26:55 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
Vary: Accept
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "autor": "7eda27d2-5205-456e-9582-7f33b022dd5b",
            "contenido": "No por mucho _madrugar_, amanece más __temprano__.",
            "contenido_html": "<p>No por mucho <em>madrugar</em>, amanece más <strong>temprano</strong>.</p>",
            "data": {
                "autorizo": {
                    "nombre": "Dr. Marcos"
                },
                "elaboro": [
                    {
                        "nombre": "Lupita"
                    }
                ],
                "reviso": "Hugo grande"
            },
            "id": "7a09d345-27cc-45ef-bf58-488354c25239",
            "notify": false,
            "pub_date": "2011-09-30",
            "revision": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

## Pregunta

¿Qué debo hacer para que no se elimine esa diagonal final? Y si es posible, ¿podrían explicarme por qué me pasó esto?

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diagonal o slash `/` se elimina automáticamente porque `ngResource` tiene un provider llamado [`$resourceProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/provider/$resourceProvider) que controla si dicha diagonal debe incluirse o no.

Para desabilitar ese cambio automático basta con cambiar la configuración `stripTrailingSlashes` en algún `config` de tu aplicación.

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  resourceConfig.$inject = ['$resourceProvider'];

  function resourceConfig($resourceProvider){
      $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
  }

  angular.module('cmi')
    .config(resourceConfig);
})();
```